# Is it possible to add an intervalometer to a Nikon D3200 with a replacement firmware?

Tags: nikon, firmware, intervalometer

I wonder if there is the possibility to add an intervalometer option via firmware to a Nikon D3200 (similar to the one in the D5200). I want to do time lapse photography and also mount the camera on a drone for special uses. In this case I need to take pictures every two seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You may want to [follow this location](http://simeonpilgrim.com/nikon-patch/nikon-patch.html) for any 3rd party firmware updates for that feature besides any Nikon updates for that model. But in the meantime, your best bet is an external [lightweight unit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y2YTEE) that can be taped to the drone. Here's one helpful [guide](http://www.superstokedmagazine.com/article/2013/10/how-to-time-lapse-with-nikon-d3200-a-how-to-time-lapse-guide/).

Comment: Um, may want to change the link to [nikonhacker.com](http://www.nikonhacker.com), since most of the information links on Simeon Pilgrim's page direct there, anyway.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I was suspecting that, and I was looking for a way so save weight for the drone. You are right a light weight wired soultion is the way to go.